# Proof regarding divergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

How can one prove that if  $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n $ converges and $a_n \geq |b_n|$ only for non-prime values of $n$,  $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n $ is not necessarily convergent ?

I'm not sure how to attack this problem, but it really seems pretty interesting .
Any ideas ?

Comment: The “not necessarily convergent” part suggests you should find an example where $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, $a_n \geq |b_n|$ if and only if $n$ is prime, and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_n$ diverges.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $$a_{n}=\frac{1}{n^{2}},\, b_{n}=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{p}, & n=p\textrm{ is a prime}\\
\frac{1}{n^{2}}, & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
 then$$a_{n}\geq b_{n}$$
 only if $n$
  is non prime, but$$\underset{n\geq1}{\sum}b_{n}\geq \underset{p}{\sum}\frac{1}{p}=\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

You should look for a counter-example. Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ be any convergent series, and take for instance $b_p=a_p$ for all prime numbers $p$.

Now, you are free to choose $b_n$ for non-prime $n$ *however you want to*. Can you make some choice that makes $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ divergent?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant non-prime values, but I think that doesn't make any difference